What's the relation between Generalized Policy Iteration (GPI), Actor-Critic, and Q-learning methods?
It seems to me that Generalized Policy Iteration (GPI) and Actor-Critic are the same, and Q-learning methods are a separate family of algorithms. I think both GPI and Actor-Critic describe the iterative process of policy evaluation (critic) and policy improvement (actor), while Q-learning is only bootstrapping using the Bellman optimality equation.
To elaborate on my understanding: Policy evaluation (critic) is done via Monte-Carlo or temporal difference methods, including function approximation if necessary, and policy improvement (actor) can be done by being greedy (tabular case) or using the policy gradient theorem (large state space). Q-learning is not doing any of these. It's just trying to estimate the $Q^\ast$ using the Bellman optimality equation by iteratively fitting the Bellman optimality equation for Q value.
I would appreciate it if anyone can confirm whether my understanding is correct or give a more systematic/precise summary of the taxonomy of online RL algorithms.

GPI is a broad framework for RL that encompasses many specific methods and algos which consists of two interacting processes of policy evaluation and improvement. And obviously actor-critic method as a subclass of policy gradient methods falls under the GPI framework as you roughly described yet it mostly improves policy via parameterized policy in a function approximation setting.
You're right that Q-learning as a value-based method differs from actor-critic methods in that it directly and explicitly aims to learn the optimal action-value Q* function via Bellman optimality equation with its nice theoretical fixed point convergence property instead of maintaining a separate policy of an actor. Thus Q-learning's policy is implicitly represented by its tabular Q-values. However, it still falls under GPI framework due to its iterative nature and goal of finding an (implicit) optimal policy through the learned optimal Q* function after cycles of evaluation and improvement.

Could you explain more about why Q-learning "still falls under GPI framework"? I thought Q-learning is looking for $Q^\ast$ directly, while "evaluation and improvement" should refer to $Q$. Also, if you count Q-learning as GPI, why is it not actor-critic then? (It can be parameterized.)

It's just that Q-learning does not include the explicit parametric policy function typical of Actor-Critic methods. but does indeed constantly evaluates and improves an implicit policy even for your mentioned parameterized DQN which amortizes action-value function acting like a critic, but a critic learns a parameterized explicit policy function. Also you can refer to page 87 with a graph of Sutton & Barto's RL book to confirm all RL methods fall under GPI framework.

From my understanding, Q-learning is constantly improving its estimate for $Q^\ast$, and $Q^\ast$ corresponds to the optimal policy $\pi^\ast$. Is $\pi^\ast$ the "implicit policy" you referred to? If so, it does not "improves" it, but improves the behavior policy. I think GPI (as shown in the picture you mentioned) must estimate and improve the same policy throughout.

Most Q-learning is off-policy and your optimal policy is the target policy which is really improved implicitly in my above argument since the behavior policy in this case is always fixed. However, you could have on-policy Q-learning which the same behavior policy gets improved iteratively and again implicitly. So they all could be said to fall under GPI as claimed by Sutton et al. Hope this clarifies.

Here is my understanding, and I would appreciate confirmation/correction: In Q-learning (say, tabular case), a Q-table represents the estimate for $Q^\ast$. The "target policy" $\pi_t$ is greedy w.r.t. Q-table, and the "behavior policy" $\pi_b$ is $\epsilon$-greedy w.r.t. Q-table. The algorithm improves the Q-table via the Bellman optimality equation based on samples collected. Thus, both the target and the behavior policies are improved as they become closer to the optimal policy. So if it's GPI, the "evaluation" is for $\pi^\ast$, and "improvement" is for both $\pi_t$ and $\pi_b$.

From algos I saw for tabular off-policy Q-learning the behavior policy is always fixed (it's possible to improve like its on-policy version) and doesn't need to be improved since it's solving the Bellman optimality equation which doesn't depend on any specific policy. And usually the advantage of off-policy Q-learning is flexibility and sample efficiency through experience replay buffer which also doesn't need to be improved at all. We only care to improve the target policy. Thus updating Q values also doesn't mean we evaluate any specific policy explicitly.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
